# Show that if p is an odd prime and $p\mid({a^2}^{r}+1)$ for some $a>1$, then $p\equiv 1\pmod {2^{r+1}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Show that if p is an odd prime and $p\mid({a^2}^{r}+1)$ for some $a>1$, then $p\equiv 1\pmod {2^{r+1}}$

I'm really not sure where to start. Also, I'm not allowed to use primitive roots.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that the order of $a$ modulo $p$ is $2^{r+1}$. Then using FLittleT, and the definition of order, you can arrive at the desired conclusion.